# When sails default model attributes get their values?

Tags: node.js, model, sails.js

When sails fill default global attributes which we added on `config/models.js` ,
default settings looks like :

```
attributes: {
  id: { type: 'number', autoIncrement: true },
  createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true },
  updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true },
}
```

Now if we add sth like `creatorId` to this default attributes , how we should fill it once for all our `models` ?

```
attributes: {
  id: { type: 'number', autoIncrement: true },
  createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true },
  updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true },
  creatorId: { type: 'number'}
}
```

After this change , all models have `creatorId` with `0` value , how I can set `userId` to all of my models `creatorId` before save without repeating my self?

Comment: What do you want to set it to? A default value, or do you want to pass it in?

Comment: @Canis I want to set current `logged-in` user id to it, which accessible on `req.user.id`

Answer (score 3):

In the controller you are creating the entry in the database this should be quite straight forward. Let's assume that you have two models, `User`, which comes with Sails built-in authentication, and a `Thing`, something that someone can own.

In the `Thing` model, I'd change the `ownerId` to be `owner` and associate it with the `User` model like so:

```js
attributes: {
    id: { ... },
    createdAt: { ... },
    updatedAt: { ... },
    owner: {
        model: 'User',
        required: yes      // Enable this when all the stuff in the db has this set
    },
}
```

This creates an association or one-to-many relationship if you know database terminology.

Now in the controller where you create your object to be inserted:

```
Thing.create({
  someAttribute: inputs.someValue,
  someOtherAttribute: inputs.someOtherValue,
  owner: this.req.me.id
});
```

If you want to use the created object right away, append `.fetch()` to the chain after `.create({...})` like so:

```
var thing = await Thing.create({ ... }).fetch();
```

Let me know if something is unclear.

I'd actually recommend you invest the $9 in buying the SailsJS course. It's an official course, taught by the creator of SailsJS, Mike McNeil. It takes you from `npm i sails -g` to pushing to production on the Heroku cloud platform. It teaches basic Vue (parasails flavour), using MailGun, Stripe payments, and more. They link to the course on the site [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/tutorials/full-stack-java-script-with-sails)

### Update

Did some further digging, and was inspired by a couple of similar cases.

What you can do is expand your model with a custom method that wraps the `.create()` method. This method can receive the request object from your controllers, but doing this, rather than the previous suggestion, will probably be more work than just adding `ownerId: this.req.me.id,` to existing calls. I1ll demonstrate anyway.

```js
// Your model
module.exports = {
    attributes: { ... },
    proxyCreate(req, callback) {
        if(!req.body.ownerId){
            req.body.ownerId = req.me.id     // or req.user.id, cant remember 
                                             // which works here
        }
        Thing.create(request.body, callback);
    }
}
```

And in your controller:

```js
...
// Change from:
Thing.create(req.body);

// To:
Thing.proxyCreate(req);
...
```

### Update #2

Another idea I had was adding the middleware on a per-route basis. I don't know the complexity of your routes, but you can create a custom middleware for only those routes.

In `router.js` you edit your routes (I'll show one for brevity):

```js
....
'POST /api/v1/things/upload-thing': [
        { action: 'helpers/add-userid-to-ownerid' },
        { action: 'new-thing' }
],
....
```

In `helpers/add-userid-to-ownerid`:

```js
module.exports: {
    fn: function(req, res) {
        if(!req.body.ownerId){
            req.body.ownerId = req.me.id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Canis, but in this way I should fill that `owner` attribute for every `.create` of my models like : `Thing1` , `Thing2` , `Thing3` . Is there another way like middle-ware to set attribute before every `.create` call ?

Comment: @Jafarrezaei I must admit I'm confused. Do you create models without data-input? Using only default values? I'm also unsure as to why setting the attribute in the `.create()` call is a problem, as that is where you set all the other data.

Comment: yes , you are right , `.create()` is where we set all data , but I need to set auto generated value(ownerId) to set on all models without needing to mention them at create method , like how `createdAt` and `updatedAt` works

Comment: @Jafarrezaei You said that the ownerid should be the id of the currently logged in user. That id is `req.me.id`. Now you want it to be a randomly generated value automatically made by the database. I'm confused again. Can you please explain your specific use case in more detail?

Comment: yes I want user id in that attribute , I thought `createdAt` time stamp is handled by `sails` , not database , and I was looking for where sails set that timestamp , and thinking for making some code to attach user id , instead of `timestamp` to another attribute globally like how `createdAt` works

Comment: @Jafarrezaei Well, the ORM, Waterline, might be involved in the data-creation, but I'm not sure. There might also be ways to use a middleware like you say, but I feel that gets too cumbersome and not worth it, when you already have `.create()` statements setting data. Adding `..., owner: req.me.id,...` to those is a better design, and a lot more maintainable in the future. You set all your non-default data in one place. I'm sorry if that is not the answer you want.

Comment: @Jafarrezaei I looked a bit more into middleware-like functionality for you, and the closest I get is using the lifecycle of the model, where you have `beforeCreate` and similar functions. The problem is that this is on the back-end, and at that point you do not have access to the user object, and thus, not the ID.

Comment: thanks dear Canis, yes , it could be good approach if we could access user id in 'model.js`

Comment: @Jafarrezaei I have postet two updates for you with more suggestions. One is actual middle ware. Note that I have not been able to actually run the code, so beware bugs and syntax errors.